# Simple JavaScript Regex that contains both square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex of the form: najfo359f+-q3f#~[+0asa123123]a'/.df;ekfm345

Any character including numbers 0 or more times,

1 OPENING SQUARE BRACKET,

Any character including numbers 0 or more times,

A NUMBER,

1 CLOSING SQUARE BRACKET,

and any character including numbers 0 or more times,

This is what I have so far:

```
/.*[.*0*/d+].*/
```

But I can't match the simple `[2245]` and when I try to escape `\` the opening square bracket my code doesn't execute.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try your regex in [Regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/), it'll help you build it!

Comment: You need to escape square brackets.

Comment: Try `.*\[.*\d+\].*`?

Comment: `/d` should be `\d`/

Comment: If you validate, then there should be no `[` and `]` in the parts that "may contain any chars", right? Try `^[^[\]]*\[[^[\]]*\d+][^[\]]*$`

Comment: Can you have this RegEx NOT make a match if the number is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. The `0` in the middle of your regex seems a bit arbitrary and doesn't appear to be considered in any of your criteria.
2. Unsure of why you're including a `/d`, maybe you meant `\d`? A backslash `\` is used to indicate escape sequences.

You're looking for something more akin to:

```
/.*\[.*\d+\].*/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KIggTu/2/)

In context with Javascript:

```js
const pattern = /.*\[.*\d+\].*/;
console.log(pattern.test("najfo359f+-q3f#~[+0asa123123]a'/.df;ekfm345"));
console.log(pattern.test("[2245]"));
```

Comment: After I match the number I need to check whether it's odd or even. Is it possible to perform checks like this inside regular expressions?

Comment: Regex doesn't really have any concept of "odd" or "even" (or mathematics in general, for that matter). You can capture the number as part of a capturing group and then have JavaScript determine if the number is odd or even. Alternatively, you could have separate patterns to match on odd or even numbers, but it's a bit more cumbersome than just having JavaScript do the calculation for you, IMO.